# How to set up routing in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is what I've in the config/routes.php

$route['music/artist/:any'] = "music/artist/index/$1";

And I've my controller, 'artist', inside a folder music/

I tried to get the uri segment inside the index method from the artist controller but when I go to the browser with domain.com/music/artist/abc it returns page not found.

How can I make this work? But I want to have my controller inside that folder.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the uri routing user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

Use this in config/routes.php

```
$route['music/artist/(:any)/(:any)'] = "music/artist/index/$1";
```

Comment: Hi it didn't work. It seems even I comment out this route config line and then go to domain.com/music/artist/ and still display 404 page not found. It's like it didn't know there's a artist controller inside the controllers/music/ folder but other folder I created earlier inside controllers/ still works. Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Okay, I just found the issue and it works with the way I've. It's just I also have a music.php inside controllers/ so properly just conflicting each other.

Comment: Glad to know that you fixed the issue.